# Unfortunately stopping after sending network request in android using volley.

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

I am developing an app which sends the GET request to a server. 
Data is going safely to the server but after 5 seconds the app activity stopped unfortunately every time . I am using volley as networking library and running it in genymotion emulator. The server a returns a string value 0 or 1 or 2 depending on the operations.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making a network call on the main (or UI) thread, your request takes more than 5 seconds and it causes ANR.

Comment: Now the app is not stopping but after clicking the submit button , the request is being sent safely and the response  is not displaying on the screen. What is the problem???

Comment: Good to hear that your request is being sent, but it is not enough data to figure out what's wrong with the response. please post code and the stacktrace